# Git not pushing folders to GitHub, only files outside folders

Tags: git, github, push

I have a local repo on my machine, and when I try to push it to my remote repo on GitHub, only external files show up.

The directory in my computer was like this:

[image]

However, it showed up like this on GitHub:

[image]
Only the `hello.py` file was added.

I ran the following on my terminal:

```
git init
git remote add origin {repourl}
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push origin master
```

(this gave no errors)
Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Hey, you should gimme your code, then I figure out what error you make.

Comment: Are there files in the client and server folders?

Comment: Yes, for or five in each

Comment: When you use the solution of Andreas Wederbrand, what happen?

Comment: What's the output of `git log -p`? Does it show the files in the directories are added to "Initial commit"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that you already used `git add .`,

#### `git add .`

Here are 2 options why it's not working

1. This command adds all your files inside the **current directory**, so you might not be in the root folder
2. If you are using an older version of git <2, `git add -A` is the equivalent to `git add .`

[image]

---

#### Empty directories

Git will not add empty directories, in order to add those directories add an empty file inside those folders and then commit.

The convention is to add `.gitkeep` inside the desired folder.

```sh
touch client/.gitkeep
touch server/.gitkeep
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you add it? (as others pointed out, assuming you actually have files in the directories)

```
git add server
git add client
git commit -m 'added the client and server'
git push
```

Comment: I added all files, I think. I will add the commands I ran to my question

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
git add .
```

to add all the newly created files.

Comment: I added all files, I think. I will add the commands I ran to my question.

Comment: OhleC may have the right answer if the directories are empty you are not able to push them.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with GitHub. Git doesn't track empty directories:

[From the FAQ:](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F)

> Can I add empty directories?
> Currently the design of the Git index (staging area) only permits files to be listed, and nobody competent enough to make the change to allow empty directories has cared enough about this situation to remedy it.
> Directories are added automatically when adding files inside them. That is, directories never have to be added to the repository, and are not tracked on their own.
> If you really need a directory to exist in checkouts you should create a file in it. .gitignore works well for this purpose (there is also a tool MarkEmptyDirs using the .NET framework which allows you to automate this task); you can leave it empty or fill in the names of files you do not expect to show up in the directory.

So, if you want them to show up, adding a `.gitignore` is the recommended way to do it.

Comment: The directorties are not empty, though

Comment: @JoshMerrian OK. Your screenshot looked very much like there weren't.